# Solving a system of 4 equations to 4 unknowns without working on a 4th degree polynomial in one of the unknowns

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, quartics

May you solve this very interesting system of equations for me?

$d+a=-4$

$ad+b=0$

$bd+c=0$

$cd=3$

Simply replacing ends up in quartic equation, for example for $d^4+4d^3+3=0$.
But I want a more intelligent solution!!!

May you please find for me a trick to reduce the system's equation into a cubic equation, for example $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ where $x$ is a new variable related to the starting system? ( please not $d^3+3d^2-3d+3=0$).

This solution is the solution I seek for.
Thank you a lot for your time!

Comment: What is so interesting about this system of equations?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. It looks quite uninteresting, right?!

Comment: I have taken the liberty to produce a title that encompasses the subject...

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer that has been posted, hyper?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you want. However, it's fairly straightforward to eliminate variables in any way you like.

Eliminating $a$, then $b$, then $c$ gives your quartic in $d$, which factors as
$$(d + 1) (d^2 + 3 d^2 - 2 d + 3) = 0 \tag{1}$$
... but you don't want that. Well, eliminating $a$, $b$, $d$ gives
$$(c + 3) (c^3 - 3 c^2 + 9 c + 9) = 0 \tag{2}$$
Better? If not, then $a$, $c$, $d$ gives
$$(b + 3) (b^3 - 3 b^2 + 15 b + 3) = 0 \tag{3}$$
Or perhaps $d$, $b$, $c$, which yields
$$(a+3) (a^3+9a^2+21 a + 1) = 0 \tag{4}$$

As it happens,
$$a=b = c=-3 \qquad d = -1$$
is a solution to the system. Letting *Mathematica* solve the system, it looks like each of the roots of the cubics contributes to a solution; the exact expressions are messy, but the decimal forms are as follows:
$$a = -0.0486\ldots \quad b = -0.1921\ldots \quad c = -0.7592\ldots \quad d = -3.9513\ldots \\[8pt]
a = -4.4756\ldots \pm i\;0.7300\ldots \quad b = 1.5960\ldots \mp i\;3.6146\ldots \\ c = \phantom{-}1.8796\ldots \pm i\;2.8846\ldots  \quad d = 0.4756\ldots \mp i\;0.7300\ldots $$

Comment: A witty answer to a a-very-uninteresting-issue.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I was rather hoping that one of the eliminations would reveal the interesting-ness of the system, but ... nope! I guess interesting-ness is in the eye of the beholder.